# Calling FindMimeFromData from VB6

Tags: vb6, mime

```
Public Declare Function FindMimeFromData Lib "urlmon.dll" ( _
        ByVal pbc As Long, _
        ByVal pwzUrl As String, _
        pBuffer As Any, _
        cbSize As Long, _
        ByVal pwzMimeProposed As String, _
        dwMimeFlags As Long, _
        ppwzMimeOut As Long, _
        dwReserved As Long) As Long
```

In VB6, I can't seem to figure out how to pass the `pBuffer` parameter of the first 256 characters of a file.   When I try to use a `Dim buffer() As Byte` and populate that, and pass it as the parameter, it throws the error of wrong param even those of the definition is `Any`.

I've tried to use [this example](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon.findmimefromdata), but passing the entire file name from a file system doesn't seem to work.  so I have to try sending it like the C# example with the first 256 bytes of the file.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with the following Declare, and built up some code around it. There are two wrappers, GetMimeTypeFromUrl() and GetMimeTypeFromData(). I found the former only worked when you used simple URLs such as http://host.com/file.xtn. You may have to play around with the other flags.

However, the other wrapper function sounds like what you need.

Note that all the string pointers are declared As Long, and I pass the underlying UTF-16 VB string as a pointer using StrPtr().

Also note that you have to use CoTaskMemFree() to free the output ppwzMimeOut string pointer, otherwise you will leak memory.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function FindMimeFromData Lib "Urlmon.dll" ( _
    ByVal pBC As Long, _
    ByVal pwzUrl As Long, _
    ByVal pBuffer As Long, _
    ByVal cbSize As Long, _
    ByVal pwzMimeProposed As Long, _
    ByVal dwMimeFlags As Long, _
    ByRef ppwzMimeOut As Long, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long _
) As Long

'
' Flags:
'

' Default
Private Const FMFD_DEFAULT As Long = &H0

' Treat the specified pwzUrl as a file name.
Private Const FMFD_URLASFILENAME  As Long = &H1

' Internet Explorer 6 for Windows XP SP2 and later. Use MIME-type detection even if FEATURE_MIME_SNIFFING is detected. Usually, this feature control key would disable MIME-type detection.
Private Const FMFD_ENABLEMIMESNIFFING  As Long = &H2

' Internet Explorer 6 for Windows XP SP2 and later. Perform MIME-type detection if "text/plain" is proposed, even if data sniffing is otherwise disabled. Plain text may be converted to text/html if HTML tags are detected.
Private Const FMFD_IGNOREMIMETEXTPLAIN  As Long = &H4

' Internet Explorer 8. Use the authoritative MIME type specified in pwzMimeProposed. Unless FMFD_IGNOREMIMETEXTPLAIN is specified, no data sniffing is performed.
Private Const FMFD_SERVERMIME  As Long = &H8

' Internet Explorer 9. Do not perform detection if "text/plain" is specified in pwzMimeProposed.
Private Const FMFD_RESPECTTEXTPLAIN  As Long = &H10

' Internet Explorer 9. Returns image/png and image/jpeg instead of image/x-png and image/pjpeg.
Private Const FMFD_RETURNUPDATEDIMGMIMES  As Long = &H20

'
' Return values:
'
' The operation completed successfully.
Private Const S_OK          As Long = 0&

' The operation failed.
Private Const E_FAIL        As Long = &H80000008

' One or more arguments are invalid.
Private Const E_INVALIDARG  As Long = &H80000003

' There is insufficient memory to complete the operation.
Private Const E_OUTOFMEMORY As Long = &H80000002

'
' String routines
'

Private Declare Function lstrlen Lib "Kernel32.dll" Alias "lstrlenW" ( _
    ByVal lpString As Long _
) As Long

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "Kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByVal pDest As Long, ByVal pSrc As Long, ByVal nCount As Long)

Private Declare Sub CoTaskMemFree Lib "Ole32.dll" ( _
    ByVal pv As Long _
)

Private Function CopyPointerToString(ByVal in_pString As Long) As String

    Dim nLen            As Long

    ' Need to copy the data at the string pointer to a VB string buffer.
    ' Get the length of the string, allocate space, and copy to that buffer.

    nLen = lstrlen(in_pString)
    CopyPointerToString = Space$(nLen)
    CopyMemory StrPtr(CopyPointerToString), in_pString, nLen * 2

End Function

Private Function GetMimeTypeFromUrl(ByRef in_sUrl As String, ByRef in_sProposedMimeType As String) As String

    Dim pMimeTypeOut    As Long
    Dim nRet            As Long

    nRet = FindMimeFromData(0&, StrPtr(in_sUrl), 0&, 0&, StrPtr(in_sProposedMimeType), FMFD_DEFAULT, pMimeTypeOut, 0&)

    If nRet = S_OK Then
        GetMimeTypeFromUrl = CopyPointerToString(pMimeTypeOut)
        CoTaskMemFree pMimeTypeOut
    Else
        Err.Raise nRet
    End If

End Function

Private Function GetMimeTypeFromData(ByRef in_abytData() As Byte, ByRef in_sProposedMimeType As String) As String

    Dim nLBound          As Long
    Dim nUBound          As Long
    Dim pMimeTypeOut     As Long
    Dim nRet             As Long

    nLBound = LBound(in_abytData)
    nUBound = UBound(in_abytData)

    nRet = FindMimeFromData(0&, 0&, VarPtr(in_abytData(nLBound)), nUBound - nLBound + 1, StrPtr(in_sProposedMimeType), FMFD_DEFAULT, pMimeTypeOut, 0&)

    If nRet = S_OK Then
        GetMimeTypeFromData = CopyPointerToString(pMimeTypeOut)
        CoTaskMemFree pMimeTypeOut
    Else
        Err.Raise nRet
    End If

End Function

Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim sRet        As String
    Dim abytData()  As Byte

    sRet = GetMimeTypeFromUrl("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx", vbNullString)

    Debug.Print sRet

    abytData() = StrConv("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Stuff</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>Test me</BODY></HTML>", vbFromUnicode)

    sRet = GetMimeTypeFromData(abytData(), vbNullString)

    Debug.Print sRet

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much.  api calls always throw me for a loop.   why are you able to change the signature of the FindMimeFromData declaration. why didn't ANY allow a byte().  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @user1161137 You can change the signature of any pointer type (array, string or object) to ByVal As Long. You can't pass a Byte array to an Any parameter, because you can't pass an array to a non-array parameter, unless it is a Variant. I suppose you could pass a Byte array to a parameter declared as an array of Any. However, I don't know how it would treat the data.